# Unexpected cast from a GridView to a HeaderGridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am using the HeaderGridView from google to add a header on a gridview.
but when I want to get the gridView from the xml I have an unexpected cast

```
HeaderGridView gridView;

gridView = (HeaderGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

I know that the R.id.gridView is a GridView and not a HeaderGridView but the HeaderGridView class extends GridView so it should work no ?

Answer (score 1):

You can *not* cast a `GridView` that isn't a `HeaderGridView` to a `HeaderGridView`
A way to remember that is: Where would it get it's information on how to "be" a `HeaderGridView`?

You can only cast up the inheritance hierarchy freely, going down you need to do type checks with `instanceof`. So you can go from `HeaderGridView` cast to `GridView`, but in order to go the other way safely, you should check types or else you may get a `ClassCastException`